# Building FFmpeg.NET .dll

Tags: c#, .net, dll, build, ffmpeg

I need to use some FFmpeg functions in C# (to be precise, in GTK#). So I downloaded wrapper [FFmpeg.NET](http://ffmpegdotnet.codeplex.com/). After that I try to build FFmpeg.NET.2008.sln(reference: I will build dll in Visual Studio 2008, but will use in GTK#), then get the following errors:

> Error 1   error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Performing
>   Makefile project actions" FFMpeg.NET
>   Error 2   The referenced assembly
>   "C:\Users\Zhenya\Documents\ffmpegdotnet-94877\bin
>   (debug shared)\ffmpeg.net.dll" was not found. If this assembly is
>   produced by another one of your projects, please make sure to build
>   that project before building this one.

How to fix these issues?
Or how to correctly build this wrapper to get .dll?

Comment: Just FYI it might be easier to accomplish your end goal but invoking the ffmpeg.exe from within your C# code.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal will it be cross platform?

Comment: It can be. You just have to include the various versions of ffmpeg in your output directory. Are you planning to run on mono or something?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I planning to use it in gtk# now, after that I will use it in xamarin.ios and xamarin.android.

Comment: Alright, I don't know a damned thing about either of those but the short answer is, if there is an assembly for that runtime available then yes it will work there.

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg for .NET includes very old version ffmpeg. I use ffmpeg.exe directly. For example

```
    void RunFfmpeg()
    {
        ffmpegProcess = new Process
            {
                EnableRaisingEvents = true,
                StartInfo =
                    {
                        FileName = GetFfmpegPath(),
                        Arguments = ffmpegParams.ToString(),
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                    },
            };
        ffmpegProcess.Start();
        ffmpegProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
        ffmpegProcess.WaitForExit();
    }
```

Comment: is it cross platform?

Comment: Don't see any problems if UseShellExecute = false But I tested it only in Windows